# Freebsd printf location in kernel

Tags: printing, kernel, scheduler, freebsd

I'm trying to modify the scheduler in FreeBSD 10 so I want to be able to do some printing to test things. I'm currently modifying /usr/src/sys/kern/kern_switch.c and in runq_add() I added printf("PRIORITY = %u\n", (unsigned int)pri); to print out the priority of the thread. I don't know if this is working as I haven't found where it prints to. How can I view the output of the printf or is there a better way to test code in the kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel printf() prints to the console, so you would see if it worked or not.  Unless it made the kernel crash or deadlock.  So, first thing would be to make sure you're building the kernel with INVARIANTS and WITNESS.  For development you want them enabled anyway, in all cases except for benchmarking.